# error while using spring.formInput in Freemarker template

Tags: jquery, css, spring-boot, freemarker, velocity

I am trying to use

```
<@spring.formInput "searchForm.frm_surName" 
   maxlength=40 
   class='form-control form-control-sm' 
   placeholder="Last Name"
/>
```

but it gives me error when I use '@' in starting of the tag, it accepts when I remove it and no error.
Also the CSS does not work for example the placeholder does not show in output and input box just shows up but is not active to use.
Any suggestions.
[Inactive input box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2eaT.png)

Comment: Please always include the (complete) error message. Also, if you remove the `@`, then it will be just static content for FreeMarker, like any random HTML tag, that's why it won't fail. CSS is not related to FreeMarker.

Comment: I cannot add CSS class or Placeholder or length for spring input in Freemarker ?

Comment: I guess you can, I just tried to say that FreeMarker doesn't interfere with that. Did you check if the HTML output contains the class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

To use spring inputs and bindings we have to import spring.ftl file for freemarker. Velocity framework does not need such import but freemarker does. So just import the file by using code below.

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
```